# Using arc4Random on Android with NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

Im using arc4Random in my cocos2d-x (V 2.2.4) project.

On MacOS I can simply use it and for linux I'm including the bsd-header (bsd/bsd.h) which I manually installed on my system. I now want to compile it natively for android and getting the error:

> jni/../../Classes/Scenes/GameScene.cpp:29:25: fatal error: bsd/bsd.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

I managed to enhance the existing Makefile. My Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
../../Classes/Scenes/MainMenuScene.cpp \
../../Classes/Scenes/GameScene.cpp \
../../Classes/BackgroundLayer.cpp \
../../Classes/VisibleRect.cpp \
../../Classes/Utils.cpp \
../../Classes/ScoreLayer.cpp \
../../Classes/HudLayer.cpp \
../../Classes/Animations.cpp \
../../Classes/Entities/Monster.cpp \
../../Classes/Scenes/SettingsScene.cpp \
../../Classes/Entities/Kitty.cpp \
../../Classes/Utils/md5.cpp \
../../Classes/Utils/ScreenLog.cpp \
../../Classes/Entities/StaticKitty.cpp \
../../Classes/Entities/FatKitty.cpp \
../../Classes/Entities/RocketKitty.cpp \
../../Classes/Entities/MovingKitty.cpp \
../../Classes/Input/GestureDetector.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
    /usr/incude/bsd/bsd.h \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/Scenes/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/Input/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/Utils/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/Entities/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../extensions/CocoStudio/Json/rapidjson/ \

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += chipmunk_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos2dx)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libcurl)
$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android)
$(call import-module,extensions)
$(call import-module,external/Box2D)
$(call import-module,external/chipmunk)
```

I think I'd also have to compile the bsd stuff for android, right?

How can I get this to work? Or is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling and waiting for replies I've come to the conclusion that it is best to just swap arc4random-calls with simple c++ rand-calls. I have not been able to compile this for armeabi although it should be possible because the whole BSD project is available for it. But it's not worth the stress ;)